# How to get another app name with packages/uri?

Tags: android, google-play-services

How can i get the name of the app from the package name. I don't want the name of my app. Here is my code:

```
   String packName ="com.apphousebd.ramadan2017";
   final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
   ApplicationInfo ai;

try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( packName, 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    ai = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

Comment: Is the application with package name "com.apphousebd.ramadan2017" installed on the phone? What error you get?

Comment: I get null value. And no it is not installed on the phone.

Comment: It should be installed on the phone to work!

Comment: but how can i get using uri? like: market://details?id=com.apphousebd.ramadan2017